# Проблема с использованием символьных классов в регулярном выражении

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, re

Очередная задача для определения валидности емэйла, но с необычным 3-им условием:

1. Емэйл не содержит пробелов;
2. Емэйл содержит символ @ ;
3. После @ есть точка, но в правильном адресе точка не должна стоять сразу после @ ( @. не должно быть в строке).

Я пользовалась regex и с его помощью написала часть кода, которая видит условие "@." Вот она:

```
(@[-\.])
```

Но я не могу понять, как мне сделать эту часть отрицательно?! Поставить крышечку ^?! Но куда?! Между @ и [?!

И ещё я переживаю, что программа будет выдавать False, если увидит любую точку, которая будет после знака @.
Т.е. и good.email@.example.com будет False и good.email@example.com тоже False(а по сути True).

Ну и вот весь код целиком для полноты картины:

```
import re
symbols = r"^\S+[-\w\.\@]+^(@[-\.])$"
email = str(input())
print(bool(re.findall(symbols, email)))
```

Comment: Крышкой нужно перечень символов в квадратных скобках начинать, например `[^\.]`

Comment: `r"\S+@[^.]\S*\.\S+"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4. В имени хоста не должно идти 2 точки подряд.

Искомое выражение:

```
\S+@[^.\s]+(?:\.[^.\s]+)+
```

Где:
`\S+` - Любые не пробельные символы
`@` - Собственно сам символ @
`[^.\s]+` - Любые не пробельные символы, но не точка. В количестве от одного и больше.
`(?:\.[^.\s]+)+` - Последовательность из символа точка и ненулевого количества не пробельных символов и не точки. Эта последовательность может повторяться много раз, но не менее одного.

И если надо сверить строку на полное соответствие, то резонно использовать `re.fullmatch()` для этого.

```
import re

for email in (  "a", 
                "a@b", 
                "a@.c", 
                "a@b.c", 
                "a.x@b.c.d", 
                "a..x@bbb.dd44", 
                "a55@bbb..hhhj", 
                "aa.@bb.cc." ):
    print(email, "=>", bool(re.fullmatch(r"\S+@[^.\s]+(?:\.[^.\s]+)+", email)))
```

```js
a => False
a@b => False
a@.c => False
a@b.c => True
a.x@b.c.d => True
a..x@bbb.dd44 => True
a55@bbb..hhhj => False
aa.@bb.cc. => False
```

Comment: раньше я хотела большую и чистую любовь, теперь так же разбираться в регулярках

Comment: @ВикаМельникова, https://regex101.com/ тренируйтесь и будет Вам счастье )))